# Pre-trained LDA models on tweets?

Tags: lda, tweets, topic-modeling

I have been looking for a pre-trained LDA model which is trained on tweets but with no avail. I want to use such a model which is trained on a large corpus to infer topics of small documents. Please share if you any?

Comment: [4. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: if SO doesn't allow me to ask this question, what's the purpose of having such relevant tags (lda, topic-modeling)? I'm not asking for a recommendation of a tool.

Comment: "Please share if you any?" sounds like you're asking for one. If you've done your homework and are trying to compare A vs B vs C, then that's on-topic if you ask a specific-enough question. If you're trying to write your own, then rewrite the question. Please give the FAQ a quick read. I'm only trying to help you.

Comment: @Ghanem  no, i ended up training a training my own model in the end.